# How do I access member variables inside of an event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript:

```
var testObj = function() {
    this.test1 = "123";
}


testObj.prototype = {
    myFunc: function() {
        var input = $('<input type=button value="clickme" />');
        $('body').append(input);
        input.click(function () {
            alert(this.test1);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    var t = new testObj();
    t.myFunc();
});
```

I know why the `alert` statement is showing undefined, but how do I make it show the actual value of `test1` variable.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Mtu/4/) has the sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

http://jsfiddle.net/33Mtu/7/

```
myFunc: function() {
    var self = this;
    var input = $('<input type=button value="clickme" />');
    $('body').append(input);
    input.click(function () {
        alert(self.test1);
    });
},
```

When you say `this` inside the click function, `this` refers to the clicked item. I set `self` to `this` so you can safely use `self` inside the click function

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a reference to the object to access it, `this` on an event refers to the sender:

```
 myFunc: function() {
        var input = $('<input type=button value="clickme" />');
        $('body').append(input);
        var obj = this;
        input.click(function () {
            alert(obj.test1);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var testObj = function() {
    test1 = "123";
}


testObj.prototype = {
    myFunc: function() {
        var input = $('<input type=button value="clickme" />');
        $('body').append(input);
        input.click(function () {
            alert(test1);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    var t = new testObj();
    t.myFunc();
});
```